# Two listViews bound one dataSource, two filters - second override the first one ... why?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling the WPF problem that can be generalized like this:

1. Having two ListViews

   ```
   <ListView x:Name="listView1"></ListView>
   <ListView x:Name="listView2"></ListView>
   ```
2. In the codebehind the Filters for them are created:

   ```
   var listViewCollection1 = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
   listViewCollection1.Filter = item => (item as string).Length == 5;
   listView1.ItemsSource = listViewCollection1;

   var listViewCollection2 = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
   listViewCollection2.Filter = item => (item as string).Length == 3;
   listView2.ItemsSource = listViewCollection2;

   public ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>()
                                                   {
                                                       "John",
                                                       "Jan",
                                                       "Lanny",
                                                       "Carol",
                                                       "Hug",
                                                   };

   public ObservableCollection<string> Items
   {
       get
       {
           return items;
       }
       private set
       {
           items = value;
       }
   }
   ```
3. The second filter overrides the first one and following items are displayed in both listViews:

   - Jan
   - Hug
4. Can anyone tell me, what's wrong? How can I properly instantiate two listViews bound to one data source, having two different filters?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Both `ListView`s are essentially bound to the same view of the same collection, you set the filter once and then override it.

Remember when you're getting a reference to an object, you don't create a *copy* of it, you *reference* it. Just because that reference is named differently does not make it different.

You can find this out by running a debugger and breaking on the second filter, you will note that before the line runs, the filter is set to a lambda filtering with a length of 5, and then you are *changing* it to a length of 3.

To achieve what you want, you would need to create another `CollectionViewSource`, with the `Source` set to the original list.

```
var listViewCollection1 = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
listViewCollection1.Filter = item => (item as string).Length == 5;
listView1.ItemsSource = listViewCollection1;

var newView = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = Items };
var listViewCollection2 = (ListCollectionView)newView.View; // Here the View must be used
listViewCollection2.Filter = item => (item as string).Length == 3;
listView2.ItemsSource = listViewCollection2;
```

*(Note: Untested, but the principle should be sound)*

Comment: Hi Rudi,

thanks for quick reply.
Is there a way to provide a filtering just on the view level of the ListView?

Just need to have several listViews as perspectives over data, bound to one data source

Can that be handled via CollectionViewSource approach?

Many thanks, Ondra

Comment: Please see my updated answer, you can simply instantiate a new `CollectionViewSource`, with the `Source` of this set to the collection :)

Comment: @OndraDvorak Thanks for your edit. Welcome to StackOverflow and +1 on your Q for completion :)

Answer (score 0):

They are referring to the same view object. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx)